# Storing properties in JNDI? Environment specific locations

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, jndi, directory

I want access to a storage folder but its actual location can vary with environments. Could I store properties into JNDI or do something similar to a datasource in JBOSS? How would I go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular way to pass parameter in Java EE application is through the property in the deployment descriptor using `env-entry`. They will be bound in the JNDI so that you can inject them.

```
<env-entry>
<env-entry-name>docroot_path</env-entry-name>
<env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
<env-entry-value>/usr/local/foo</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After reading your post before you put in example code I found some <env-entry> examples.